# Keeping format when parsing text from a site

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack, text-parsing

I want to parse text from a whole website, and all the text appear in a text file like raw text. I would like to make it formatted as is.

I am using HTML Agility Pack to parse the text, I tried any solution I can find on the internet but nothing really helps. This is my code.

```
 var headerNames = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//[@id='wrap']/div[2]/div/div/div[3]").ToList();
        foreach (var item in headerNames)
        {
            var completeReplace = item.InnerText.Replace("<br>, </b>","\n");
            Console.WriteLine(completeReplace);
        }
```

Seems like the Replace does not work, or I miss something about it. Or you guys can help me with another way to parse the text, I appreciate it.

Comment: Replace does not take an array of strings to replace, just 1 literal string. Do two calls.

Comment: Hi, can you tell me in a more specific way? I don't really get it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use replace function like that. It only replace one segment at a time.

```
var headerNames = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//[@id='wrap']/div[2]/div/div/div[3]").ToList();
foreach (var item in headerNames)
{
    var completeReplace = item.InnerText.Replace("<br>","\n");
    completeReplace = completeReplace .Replace("</br>","\n");
    Console.WriteLine(completeReplace);
}
```

Comment: So, what should I use for that purpose?

Comment: I can't understand you. sorry

Comment: Something in a web page like:
"text text text
     <br/>
  other text"
But when I parse that page, what I get will be
"text text text other text"
instead of the given format.
I would like to ask how to keep the given format when parsing the web page with HTML agility pack.

Comment: you need to call item.InnerHtml, this will give you the html